# Show data from database to Array Multidimensi using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have some data like this 
[image]

but i cant create it data to array multidimensi, how to create and view array like this? thank you.

```
Array (A => array (part_no=>A, control_no=>0001, qty=>1000))
```

i try like

```
$data = array(); 
while ($r = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data_arr = array(
                  $control = $r['control_no'], $part_no= $r[part_no]); 
                  $data = $data_arr
                );
}
print_r ($data);
```

Comment: What you have tried yet in Php and Mysql ?

Comment: yup, i have update my question , please help

Comment: `[part_no_value->['part_no'=>part_no_value, 'control_no'=> control_no_value,'qty'=>qty_value]]`

Comment: how to use? in while? or in $data_arr ? :(

Comment: how are you going to handle multiple rows with same part_no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this. Note you have to use `=>` not `=` also note `used $data[]` instead of `$data`. still unclear on the output requirement. asuming you want all rows.

```
$data = array(); 
while ($r = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data_arr = array($r[part_no] => array(
            'control' => $r['control_no'], 
            'part_no'=> $r[part_no],
            'qty'=> $r[qty]
        )); 
    $data[] = $data_arr);
}
print_r ($data);
```

this will output something like

```
Array (
   [0]=> Array( A => array (part_no=>A, control_no=>0001, qty=>1000)),
   [1]=> Array( A => array (part_no=>A, control_no=>0002, qty=>1000)),
   [2]=> Array( A => array (part_no=>A, control_no=>0003, qty=>1000)),
   [3]=> Array( B => array (part_no=>B, control_no=>0004, qty=>1500)),
   ...........
)
```